# I programmed a cube to slide across the floor in scenekit for iOS, it sinks into the floor though

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, scnnode, skphysicsworld

I currently have a scene where a cube is dropped onto a floor in scenekit.  I animated the cube to move on the x axis across the floor, when it does though it sinks into the floor a bit and then repositions to be on top of the floor.

Here's just some of the code:

```
// create floor
SCNFloor *mainFloor = [SCNFloor floor];
SCNNode *floorNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:mainFloor];
floorNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, -4.0, 0.0);
[myScene.rootNode addChildNode:floorNode];
SCNPhysicsShape *ground = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:mainFloor options:nil];
SCNPhysicsBodyType kin = SCNPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic;
SCNPhysicsBody *solid = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:kin shape:ground];
floorNode.physicsBody = solid;
myScene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0.0, -9.8, 0.0);
```

Can someone help me find out why the cube sinks?  If you can't figure out why, maybe you could provide example code of a working floor that a character can walk on?  (in objective c hopefully, but i can translate from swift if need be)

Comment: is the cube scaled? eg did you edit `cube.scale`?

Comment: @ProBlaster no, I did not.

Comment: about how much (in % of the cube) does your cube fall through the floor before it re-positions?

Comment: Or, is it just a little, or is it like half the cube?

Comment: Its probably like 25% of the cube that falls through.  Depends on how far I move it in the animation sequence though

Comment: Sorry if i'm asking to many questions... However... ...What kind of animation do you use?

Comment: Can you post your animation?

Comment: I don't have any way to record it at the moment but I'm doing a course on Udemy.com and it eventually gets to physics and animations.  So, hopefully that will answer my question.  The animation is an SCNAction().

Comment: oooh... `SCNAction`, Hmm, `SCNAction` isn't very compatible with  physics-- sorry, you may want to look into [\[SCNPhysicsBody applyforce\]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNPhysicsBody/applyForce:impulse:)

Comment: @ProBlaster ohh, ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ProBlaster's advice, I used [SCNPhysicsBody applyForce] instead and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the category bit mask of your floor and the collision bitmask of your cube should be the same
you can do so (in swift) like this:

```
floorNode.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 3
cubeNode.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 3
```

Comment: That didn't work, it still does the same thing.  :-/  
Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Try making your floor physics shape of type static and your cube of type dynamic